# ¿Cómo puedo crear "x" cantidad de input según la opción marcada?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Necesito crear un div con una cantidad "x" de input según la opcióon marcada tanto en un combobox como en un input.
Ej: Al seleccionar en un combobox o escribir en un input la cantidad "3", que a continuación en un div se creen 3 inputs.
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hermano?

Comment: @fredyfx Aún no he intentado nada, pronto lo intentare, en cuanto el código en html no tiene dificultad para mi, pero que funcione lo que quiero, ahí no domino mucho el tema

Comment: dale hermano, tú puedes, eleva ese cosmos y dale con todo el power 2.0!!! intenta y aquí te damos una mano con mucho gusto :D

Comment: aprende javascript aquí: https://www.freecodecamp.org y jQuery en: https://try.jquery.com buena suerte :D (ambos enlaces son gratuitos)

Comment: Gracias por tu apoyo hermano, ya estoy adentrándome en esta materia :) Saludo

Comment: de nada hermano, aquí todos siempre estamos en constante aprendizaje, todos juntos estamos haciendo de SOes la mejor comunidad hispana de desarrolladores de software a lo largo y ancho de la red. Esperamos contar contigo, mientras vas aprendiendo vas preguntando, respondiendo y comentando, elevamos el cosmos y le damos con todo el power 2.0!!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que estas queriendo hacer seria algo así:

```js
$(function(){

  $("#mySelect").change(function(){
  var cantidad =$("#mySelect").val();
    $("#myInput").val(cantidad);
    RenderInputs(cantidad);
  });
  
  $("#myInput").change(function(){
  var cantidad = $("#myInput").val();
    $("#mySelect").val(cantidad);
    RenderInputs(cantidad);
  });

});

function RenderInputs(cantidad){
$('#content').html('');
  for (var i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
  $('#content').append('<div class="col-6">');
        $('#content').append('<label> Input ' + (i+1) + '</label>');
        $('#content').append('<input class="form-control" type="text" id="input'+(i+1)+'"/>');
        $('#content').append('</div>');
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <lavel>Cantidad</label>
      <select id="mySelect" class="form-control">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <label>Cantidad</label>
        <input id="myInput" class="form-control" type="number">
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row" id="content"></div>
```

Espero te oriente! Saludos.

Comment: Nicolas, gracias por aportar, sin embargo, deberias esperar a que el autor añada lo que ha intentado en vez de resolverselo. Un saludo

Comment: Perdón, soy nuevo en StackOverflow y mi intención es ayudar. Voy aprendiendo conforme pasan los días :) la próxima esperare! Saludos!

Comment: Nicolas muchas gracias, es exactamente la solución al problema. Recientemente he estado aprendiendo y entendiendo un poco sobre javascript, o sea que no me queda duda de tu solución y que es muy buena, y ya te digo, es justo lo que quería decir. Gracias a todos!